# Switch Net Core Application Environment within Supervisord

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, supervisord

I am currently running a Net Core based WebApi application on Ubuntu 16.04 using supervisord on our Production Server.  I now however want to run the same setup on our Development and Staging Server (they are both the same box) but as part of the supervisord setup I was wondering if it is possible to set the environment that the Core Application would use.

I have tried setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable using the supervisord environment configuration settings but this has no impact.

Can anyone advise if this should work or if there is another route I should be looking at.

Thanks,

Stuart

Comment: I don't know enough about supervisord to really make a proper answer. But while you can set environment variables, these are machine (Or container) wide. But you can actually set the environment via Code too. See here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/05/03/environments-asp-net-core/

Comment: Ideally I would like to do it at the application level in supervisord if possible.